# upper bound for the norm of leontief inverse

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a zero diagonal $n\times n$ bistochastic matrix. Let $B$ be a sub-matrix of A by deleting row and column $j$. we want to prove
\begin{align*}
    (I - B)^{-1} 1_{n-1} < n \cdot 1_{n-1}
\end{align*}
(i.e. the max row sum of $(I - B)^{-1}$ is smaller than $n$)

UPDATE 1:

I was thinking about doing to following:
Define norm $N(X)$ as

\begin{align*}
    N(X) = \max_{i} \sum_j X_{ij}
\end{align*}

Then I want to prove
\begin{align*}
N((I - B)^{-1}) = N (I + B + B^2 + B^3 + ...)< n
\end{align*}

and we know $N (I + B + B^2 + B^3 + ...) \leq N(I) + N(B) + N(B)^2 + ... <= \frac{1}{1 - N(B)}$. However, this does not complete the proof because $N(B)$ can be 1.

UPDATE 2:

I will also be glad someone can point out if the statement is not correct. From my simulation, it appears that I can confirm the above statement

```
N = 6;
mi = 01;
A=rand(N).*not(eye(N));
B=bistoch(A,1E-5)
inv(eye(N - mi) - B(1:N- mi,1:N- mi)) * ones(N- mi,1)

function a=bistoch(a,tol)
% return bistochastic matrix from input nonnegative matrix
if nargin<2, tol=0.001; end
s1=sum(a,2);
s2=sum(a);
while ((abs(max(s1)-1))>tol) | ((abs(max(s2)-1))>tol)
  a=a./s1;
  s1=sum(a,2);
  s2=sum(a);
  a=a./s2;
end
end
```

Comment: some things are missing from this.  e.g. $A=I_n$ satisfies the description and $(I-B)^{-1}$ does not exist... perhaps $A$ is irreducible?

Comment: Ohh yeahh. I forget to mention. A has zero diagonal

Comment: A having zero diagonal still isn't enough.  I can continue to generate counterexamples if $A$ is reducible, e.g. consider  $A=\begin{bmatrix} P^{(1)} &\mathbf 0\\ \mathbf 0 & P^{(2)}\end{bmatrix}$ where in each case $P$ is a permutation matrix representing permutations without fixed points, e.g. cyclic shift operator.  As before $(I-B)^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: I might misunderstand your point. Suppose the 4x4 matrix A = [0001;1000;0100;0010] is a permutation matrix, shouldn't (1-B) invertible?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. E.g. when $0<t<1$ and
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0&t&1-t&0\\ \hline t&0&0&1-t\\ 1-t&0&0&t\\ 0&1-t&t&0
\end{array}\right],
$$
we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3\end{bmatrix}
:=(I-B)^{-1}\mathbf1
=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&t-1\\ 0&1&-t\\ t-1&-t&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{t+1}{t}\\ \frac{2-t}{1-t}\\ \frac{1}{t(1-t)}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Therefore $(I-B)^{-1}\mathbf1$ is unbounded. In fact, none of its entries is bounded above, because $\lim_{t\to0}y_1=\infty$, $\lim_{t\to1}y_2=\infty$ and $\lim_{t\to0}y_3=\lim_{t\to1}y_3=\infty$.

Comment: thanks! in fact, there may not be an upper-bound

Comment: @FirstLast Yes. The idea is that when $I-B$ is close to singular, $\|(I-B)^{-1}\mathbf1\|$ can be arbitrarily large.